# Solr indexing issue with solrpy

Tags: python, solr

Just started learning solr. I am trying to use solrpy as a client. My python code is:

```
import solr

# create a connection to a solr server
s = solr.SolrConnection('http://localhost:8983/solr')

# add a document to the index
doc = dict(
    id='testid123',
    title='Lucene in Action',
    author=['Erik Hatcher', 'Otis Gospodneti'],
    )
s.add(doc, commit=True)

# do a search
response = s.query('title:lucene')
for hit in response.results:
    print hit['title']
```

This is from the example given [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/solrpy/)

My solr schema.xml is the default schema that comes with solr distribution. I have not made any changes to that. It has a uniqueKey field as "id".

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

And it is of string type

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Still when I run my code, on my client side I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user1/Documents/workspace/PyDelight/src/Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    s.add(doc, commit=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/solrpy-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/solr/core.py", line 678, in add
    return Solr.add_many(self, [fields], commit=_commit)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/solrpy-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/solr/core.py", line 326, in wrapper
    return self._update(content, query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/solrpy-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/solr/core.py", line 550, in _update
    rsp = self._post(selector, request, self.xmlheaders)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/solrpy-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
    return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/solrpy-0.9.5-py2.7.egg/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
    raise ex
solr.core.SolrException: HTTP code=400, reason=Bad Request
```

And on the solr trace side I get error:

```
843169 [qtp1151734776-20] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  ? [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true} {} 0 0
843170 [qtp1151734776-20] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id
```

schema.xml file is in solr-4.4.0/example/solr/collection1/conf

And I am running solr by simply running start.jar in example directory.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have not used solrpy much (and haven't installed it yet) but from the initial example, it looks like it wants to be called with attribute=value pairs instead of a dictionary. (i know the example you posted is right from the online 0.9.2 documentation! but the current source on github has this in the comments):

```
add(**params)
        Add a document.  Pass in all document fields as
        keyword parameters:
            add(id='foo', notes='bar')
        You must "commit" for the addition to be saved.
```

So try this:

```
s.add(commit=True, **doc)
```

and it will probably work. You may need to pull out the commit and do it separately, i don't know.

i am not a solr expert, and just played around with it a little bit, but also i had better luck using [sunburnt](https://github.com/tow/sunburnt) than solrpy. worth a shot, maybe.

edit: github pointer to that file is here: http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/source/browse/solr/core.py

Comment: Problem was indeed with the way parameters are to be passed. Still there is some issue with the 'commit' process. But on your suggestion I am going to spend some time with sunburnt. Skimmed through it and documentation looks much more detailed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Solr so I could be totally wrong, but in the example you link to the `id` is an `int`.  Try making yours an `int` as well, changing your id from `'testid123'` to something else like `123` and see what happens.